# Play a song specified by a user after a UILocalNotification fires

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

What I'm trying to achieve here is simple to describe but hard to achieve:

Given that the user has created a UILocalNotification, how can I allow them to specify a song from their own iPhone that will play after the notification fires?

I would like the user to be able to select a song from their own music list.

Furthermore, how do I ensure that the song plays even if the device is locked and the ring volume is turned off?

Comment: There is no way you can override the volume of iOS device. Apple wouldn't allow developer to override a user device like that.

Comment: Okay, I can relinquish control over that feature. But more importantly, can I access a user's songs allowing them to play them at will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with normal local notifications, as they have a limit of 30 seconds and you cannot let the user choose the file. You have to import it in your app bundle and include it in your code.

I think there is no other way then abusing the background audio playback system to keep your app running in the background, then present a local notification with no sound and play the sound out of a call in your background app with a system library (core audio etc...)

Comment: Can you give some demo code to **present a local notification with no sound and play the sound out of a call in your background app with a system library (core audio etc...)**. _Thanks in advance_.

Answer (score 1):

Apple [iOS Local and Push Notification API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) only allow custom sound that is included in the main bundle and must be under 30 seconds when played.